# Convert image (from url) to File

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

```
let url ='https://xxxx/image.jpg';
let blob = new Blob([url]);
let file = new File([blob], "filename", { type: "image/jpg"  });
```

i am working on an angular project and would love to assign an image to file for upload. However the system cannot load the image after upload. any ideas??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using fallowings:

```html
fetch('https://i.imgur.com/fHyEMsl.jpg')
    .then((res) => res.blob())
    .then((myBlob) => {debugger
       const myFile = new File([myBlob], 'image.jpeg', {type: myBlob.type});
    });
```

Comment: Thx however when i replace the url with mine it shows this error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. any ideas how to resolve it?

Comment: On the server where the image is stored, has cors enabled, so it will stops you downloading it. You may put it into an on the fly created image, by settings the src attribute, and on load event try to do almost the same as above.